# How can execute php scripts in bash?

Tags: php, bash, parse-url

I need parse uri in shell scripts. So, I tried to use php in bash as below.

```
#!/bin/sh

uri="http://www.google.com?key=value
key="host"

value=$(php -r "$parse = parse_url('$uri'); echo $parse['$key']")
```

It has showing the following error.

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in Command line code on line 1
```

Some body can help how to use embedded php in bash ?

Comment: Why don't you just make it in PHP and call the php? `php test.php` can also be called on command line same way you do with a bash script. Seems you're also more comfortable with PHP anyway.

Answer (score 4):

A cheap way of debugging this is to use `echo` to see what you're passing in to php:

```
echo "$parse = parse_url('$uri'); echo $parse['$key']"
```

shows

```
 = parse_url('http://www.google.com?key=value'); echo ['host']
```

You're already using `$uri` to mean "the value of the shell variable uri", so it's not surprising that `$parse` is also considered a shell variable and expanded to its value (unset, nothing).

Use `\$` when you want a literal dollar sign in your double quoted string:

```
value=$(php -r "\$parse = parse_url('$uri'); echo \$parse['$key']")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use it easily, but you must be careful because of escaping in bash.

I recommend to use **single quotes** (you do not need to escape anything) and exit from the quotes when you want to do something special. Your example:

```
php -r '$parse=parse_url("'$url'"); echo $parse["'$part'"];'
```

Note that

- you do not need to escapes `$parse`
- you need to exit from single quotes when inserting bash variable: `'$url'`
- you cannot use single quotes in the single quotes! do use double quotes `"` instead.

**Update:**

Just for the clarification - parse error happened because `$parse` was interpreted as bash variable (empty string) so the php command incorrectly started with `=`.